# small dplyr syntax clarification

Tags: r

Not sure why i am still stuck at this problem and tried researching around and i can't believe i am still stuck at it

How can i integrate 'between','or','and' in the same filter statement?

I thought a comma would be 'and' and | would be or so i went with the below filter statement. Not giving the intended result.

sample

```
d<-structure(list(minsell= c(31,-31,0,0),
                  maxsell= c(31,-31,0,0),
                  minbuy= c(0,0,31,31),
                  maxbuy= c(0,0,0,31)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

intended output
[image]

Code line i am using

```
testing<-testing%>%dplyr::filter(((between(minsell, 1, -31)),(between(maxsell, 1, -31)))|((between(minbuy, 31, -1))|(between(maxbuy, 31, -1))))
```

Comment: The `,` is an `&`. The dput structure is giving errors  i.e. `d %>% filter((between(minsell, 1, -31)) & (between(maxsell, 1, -31))|((between(minbuy, 31, -1))|(between(maxbuy, 31, -1))))`.  I get 0 rows based on the code

Comment: Isn't the image for intended output is the same as input.  May be you copied the wrong image

Comment: yeah, my bad. Sorry. See now

Comment: If you check the `?between` the `left` and `right` arguments  are  `x >= left & x <= right` If you mention `between(minbuy, 31, -1)` it is `minbuy >= 31 & minbuy <= -1`.  Is that what you intended

Comment: Yeah that's wrong. wanted something like filter(minsell < 1,minsell > -31 | maxsell < 1 , maxsell > -31|minbuy > -1 , minbuy < 31|maxbuy > -1 , maxbuy < 31)

Comment: Something like `d %>% filter((between(minsell, -31, 1) & between(maxsell, -31, 1)) & between(minbuy, 1, 32) & between(maxbuy, 0, 30))` as the `between` is not including the bounds

Comment: Do you know how i can put a 'or' statement between two 'between'

Comment: Just wrap the two between in a single `()` i.e. `(between(.., 1, 31) & between(..., 1, -31)) |(between(.., 1, 31) & between(..., 1, 31))`

Comment: That works, thanks alot. Can you write post so i can accept it as answer? i will adjust in my script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we want to wrap multiple expressions to be taken as a single block, then it is always recommended to wrap those in a `()` to evaluate as a single block.  Otherwise, due to precedence of operators (most languages have its own set or operator precedence, assignment precedence, etc), it can lead to different outcome.  The `between` function from `dplyr` is a shortcut for `x >= left & x <= right` i.e. it includes the bounds as well.  So, make sure the values are adjusted

```
d %>% 
    filter((between(minsell, -31, 1) & between(maxsell, -31, 1)) | 
           (between(minbuy, 1, 32) & between(maxbuy, 0, 30)))
```